# How to pass an Asyncio coroutine to a multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram

I have developed an application that works well in "asynchronous mode" and performs calculations. When the calculations meet certain criteria, a function of a "Telegram bot" is called to send the results to the bot, while the calculations continue because they are looped infinitely.

It works fine, but it's too slow.

Either my knowledge in `asyncio` is insufficient, or the functionality of this library is not capable of what I need to accomplish. So, I started to think about how to speed up the process and came to the conclusion that I need to run the main chain of functions that performs the calculations in multiple processes.

However, I faced an issue where I cannot get asynchronous code to work inside the processes, no matter how hard I tried. Moreover, I need to add separate asynchronous work for the Telegram bot somewhere in my application. I have tried using `multiprocessing` and `aioprocessing`, but nothing seems to work.

```
async def main():
    try:
        pairs = [[..., ...], [..., ...], [..., ...], [..., ...], [..., ...]]
        tasks_run = [func(pair) for pair in pairs]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks_run)
    except Exception:
        logger.exception('main')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    tasks = [loop.create_task(dp.start_polling()), loop.create_task(main())]
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

I need to create a separate process for each pair and run the coroutine func(pair) in it. Is it
possible to use multiprocessing and asyncio together? If yes, how can I do that? If not, how can I solve my problem differently?

By the way, in `if __name__ == '__main__'`, two tasks are created. One runs a Telegram bot, and the other runs the calculation chain. And something tells me that adding process execution will somehow break the interaction between the Telegram bot and the calculations themselves.

Please don't judge me too harshly, I've only been programming for six months.

Comment: The idea of asynchronous processes is to handle the case where your application has to wait around for something external to it to respond. That is for situations where you are waiting for IO (input/output) operations. If you have a cpu intensive process then yeah you want multiprocessing, or if possible dividing up work on multiple machines. Asyncio can be used in the latter case, that is farming out the work to other machines. Presumably it could have multithreading in it, but it seems hacky and I have never tried it myself.

Comment: so you are proposing the use of `asyncio` and `multiprocessing` simultaneously ?

Comment: By "calculations" I meant data processing, and by data processing, I mean making requests to cryptocurrency exchanges (this is where I need Asyncio), receiving responses, and further processing the data received. The amount of data received is so large that it would take an unrealistically long time to process it synchronously.

Comment: My application parses data for all trading pairs from multiple cryptocurrency exchanges and looks for price differences between exchange A and exchange B. When a price difference is found for a trading pair, a message with further instructions is sent to the Telegram bot. That is why I have separated exchanges into pairs, and why I need to run each pair in a separate process. Additionally, everything inside this process should be executed asynchronously; otherwise, the signal in the Telegram bot will be invalid. This is my situation.

Comment: Am I correct from your description that speed is of essence when a difference in prices is found e.g. you want to exploit the difference before others do and have to respond ASAP? Or is it that you are using the price difference merely as a technical indicator and split seconds do not count?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run CPU-intensive computations in parallel inside an AsyncIO run loop, you can use `asyncio.run_in_executor()` together with a process pool:

```py
import asyncio
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def heavy_work(i: int) -> int:
    """CPU intensive function"""
    sleep(1.0)
    return i


async def main():
    start = perf_counter()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        r1, r2 = await asyncio.gather(
            loop.run_in_executor(pool, heavy_work, 1),
            loop.run_in_executor(pool, heavy_work, 2),
        )

        print(r1, r2)

    elapsed = perf_counter() - start
    print(f"Time: {elapsed:.2f} s")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

On a two-core computer you'll see that the elapsed time is approximately one second instead of the two seconds it would have taken if run serially.

Alternatively, if you need to offload IO-bound operations or functions that release the GIL, you can une a `ThreadPoolExecutor` which will perform better and will avoid pickle issues.

As a final note, you may have noticed that the function `heavy_work` is not async. This is intended since async functions should not contain any CPU-intensive work since this will block the event loop. If you want to make such a function async, then you'll have to offload the CPU-intensive part to a process pool. Here is an example using a global shared process pool:

```py
SHARED_PROCESS_POOL = ProcessPoolExecutor()

async def heavy_work(i: int) -> int:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    
    # Isolated CPU-intensive work
    await loop.run_in_executor(SHARED_PROCESS_POOL, sleep, 1.0)

    return i
```

The same thing using a thread pool is much simple since you can use the dedicated `asyncio.to_thread` function.